# Google Cloud Platform: How to delete a folder containing active resources?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I have been managing a Google Workspace account (G Suite Legacy Free Edition).

I am now closing that Google Workspace account. However I am currently unable to do so because of an issue I am encountering on Google Cloud.

Before closing my Google Workspace account, I needed to use Google Cloud to export a single user's data. I was able to do this successfully

Two days ago I went to this URL https://admin.google.com/ac/companyprofile/accountmanagement to delete my Google Workspace account. The option to delete my account was not available, the page said 'You have active projects in Google Cloud Platform. You need to delete all GCP projects before you can delete this account.'

I went to https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager?authuser=0 and deleted my data export for that single user. This currently shows up under 'Resources pending deletion' (https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager?pendingDeletion=true&authuser=0).

However today I still cannot close my Google Workspace account and I get the same message about active projects.

I contacted Google Workspace Support and they said:

> "Hi! Resources pending deletion will not stop the deletion of
> Workspace, the message you received is because an active project has
> been detected, please follow these steps to look for it:
>
> 1. Go to GCP console
> 2. On the sidebar, go to IAM & Admin -> Identity and Organization 2A. If your listing is under a project, it will show something like "Page
>    not viewable for projects." Next to it, make sure the domain is
>    selected and click the select button. 2B. Under Set Permissions, click
>    "Set Permissions".
> 3. If you are listed under the members, edit your user. If not, add yourself.
> 4. For your roles, add: Organization Admin and Folder admin. Save your new roles.
> 5. Now, back to the project list and delete everything."

I followed their instructions but on the page 'Identity & Organisation' after selecting a domain I could not see any link or section titled Set Permissions.

Remembering a Permissions section on the Manage Resources page I added my Google Workspace admin email address as a Principal to my domain with the following roles:
billing account creator
folder admin
organisation administrator
owner
project creator

Please see a screenshot attached to this post:

[Google cloud resource permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ1ug.png)

I went back to the Manage Resources page and ticked the check box next to my domain but the Delete link was greyed out (i.e. not clickable). I noticed that the node could be expanded so I clicked that which revealed a folder called 'system-gsuite'. When I expanded that folder it contained another folder within it called 'apps-script'.

I ticked the checkbox next to the apps-script folder and clicked the Delete link but the web page displayed the message 'Folder cannot be deleted as it contains active resources. Only empty folders can be deleted.'

I contacted Google Workspace Support again and asked them how to overcome this issue. They said I should find help on online communities.

**Does anyone have any suggestions to help me delete all my Google Cloud projects?**

I did try the alternative approach of shutting down my Google Cloud project (https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6251787) but unfortunately when I go to the URL https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings?authuser=0&organizationId=############## all I see is my organisation name and organisation ID and there are no options to take any other actions.

Thanks

## Update on September 5, 2022: My issue has been resolved

I am happy to report my issue has been solved and I have been able to successfully delete my Google Workspace account. The advice I needed was linked to from this post on the Google Workspace Community: https://support.google.com/a/thread/177790442?hl=en&msgid=177886599

Comment: Have you tried using the CLI? That might help will better error messages.  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/delete

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you for getting back to me. Thank you for your suggestion, I looked into it and it looks like Google Cloud CLI is a paid-for product? https://cloud.google.com/cli I have cancelled my Google Workspace subscription and I'm not looking to spend any money with Google, I just want to delete my Google Workspace account.

Comment: The CLI is free. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install

Comment: I am happy to report my issue has been solved and I can now delete my Google Workspace account. The advice I needed was linked to from this post on the Google Workspace Community: https://support.google.com/a/thread/177790442?hl=en&msgid=177886599 

Answer (score -1):

The answer above provides success up to a point. I was stuck because all the project files in GCP were grayed out. But I figured out a workaround and I am really hoping that this helps other people as well.

In my GCP, I could see the *projects* associated with the "apps script" folder but NOT in Managed Resources, however, (and even with all of the correct permissions), there was no way to expose the *project(s)* in Managed Resources.... until I found a workaround solution.

It's a bit of a pain but will provide the desired result of being able to expose projects within the "apps-script" folder of Managed Resources and delete them.

Go to the Android/IOS Play Store and download the Google Console app and log into it with the same login used in your browser console.google.com session.

You're logged into the GCP App. There are five icons along the bottom; Dashboard, Resources, Operations, Permissions, Billing.

Steps to repeat for all Projects to expose them in the Browser Session of GCP.  (Let me just say how strange this process is and why I cannot do this in the Browser Session is beyond me).

1. In the GCP App, Click "Resources", at the top of the app there's a drop down to select one of the project(s) that GCP shows are still in use.
2. Select a project (by doing so, the App will show the Resources for that project. My projects have No Services Assigned).
3. In the GCP App, Click "Permissions". This will show the current permissions for the Project. My default permission is shown in the app for each of my projects is: appsdev-apps-dev-script-auth@system.gserviceaccount.com (owner).
4. Originally I was adding all of these permissions to each project. But then I noticed, that simply selecting the project in the GCP App made the project appear in the GCP Browser console apps-script folder without needing to add any other permissions AND I was able to proceed with deleting each project individually, and then the folders, and proceeded with step 11.

Permission for each project:
Click the "+" button in the GCP App.  You'll need to add these permissions for each and every individual project.
a. Add the GCP Admin email associated with your account
b. Click "+ Assign Roles"
c. Add "Project Billing Manager"
d. Add "Delete Service Accounts"
e. Add "Project Deleter"
f. Add "Organization Administrator"
g. Add "Project IAM Admin"
h. Add "Security Center Admin"
i. Add "Owner"

5. Once you've added all of the assigned roles for this project, Click the blue check mark in the upper right hand corner and then Click blue Save button.
6. In your GCP Browser console, Refresh the Manage Resources page.  You will see the project appear below the "apps-script" folder
7. Select the left checkbox next to the Project name and on that row click the vertical three dots button on the right. Click the Delete link. A popup comes up to "Shut down project "name-of-project"".
8. Type the Project ID into the required Project ID* field and click "Shut Down Anyway".  This will shutdown your project and move it into "Resources Pending Deletion".
9. Repeat these steps for each project using the Google Cloud App and the GCP Browser.
10. Once the projects are deleted you can delete the folders.
11. Once, these actions are complete for all your GCP Projects, login to your Google Admin Console. There shouldn't be any "active" projects warning, and you should be able to Close/Delete your Google account.

I CAN 100% Confirm that this solution works super well.
Again, I was this solution because I could not get my GCP Browser console to show the "projects" within the "apps-script" folder.  (if there's a way to show these files in Managed Resource in the apps-script folder within the GCP Browser console, please advise), otherwise, I hope this assists someone else who's having a similar issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).